# Problemas para trabajar con kivy en Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Tengo Python 2.7 y he instalado kivy.

Tiene que estar bien instalado porque cuando lo importo desde la consola de Python no me da error. Pero si sigo introduciendo código tengo problemas. Soy nueva en esto y no sé cual es el flujo de trabajo con Python y kivy.

Os pego lo que me arroja la consola por si me podéis echar una mano. Es lo siguiente:

```
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from kivy.app import App
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
>>> import kivy
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\User\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-03-01_2.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>> from kivy.app import App
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 327, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
 ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el m
```

Comment: Hola Carmen, bienvenida a SOes, creo que el traceback lo has pegado incompleto, puedes incluir la parte que falta?

Comment: Hola Cesar he pegado todo lo que salía en la consola. No hay más acaba con esa 'm'. yo también me pregunto por qué. Debe referirse a módulo, pero no se más. Tengo unos recortes de pantalla que quizá ayuden. Los voy a adjuntar. Cómo hago para adjuntarlos? Gracias por tu interés.

Comment: ¿Has instalado usando `pip` o de qué forma?

Comment: Usando Pip. Oye a parte de esto. Cómo hago para cerrar sesión en stackoverflow? Gracias

Comment: Arriba a la izquierda en donde dice "StackExchange"

Comment: Lo puedes hacer en un fichero en vez de la consola de python? Así no te corta la salida del error

Comment: > python -m pip install pillow Eso hizo que empiece a funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que he podido encontrar según la documentación es que para la instalación en Windows tienes que seguir los pasos descritos:

1. Asegúrate de tener las últimas versiones de `pip` y `wheel`:

   ```
   $ python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
   ```
2. Instala las dependencias (puedes obviar `gstreamer` (~90MB) si no lo necesitas, mira las dependencias de Kivy):

   ```
   $ python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew kivy.deps.gstreamer --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/
   ```
3. Instala `kivy`:

   ```
   $ python -m pip install kivy
   ```

A esto yo le agregaría también (si es que no lo tienes instalado) la librería `Pillow` (un fork de `PIL`):

```
$ pip install pillow
```

Intenta desinstalar `kivy` y realizar los pasos que acabo de describir.

### Referencias

- [[Kivy] User’s Guide » Installation on Windows](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html)
- [[Pillow] Installation](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.0/installation.html)